# Inferred latch occurence in verilog

Tags: verilog, latch

Implement the following circuit:

[image]

Note that this is a latch, so a Quartus warning about having inferred a latch is expected.

**This is my implementation**

```
module top_module (
input d, 
input ena,
output q);
always @(*)
    begin
        if(ena==1'b1)
            q=d;
        else
            q=q;
    end endmodule
```

Can someone help me why there is a inferred latch even though i am solving q for every case possible?

Comment: If you are implementing D flip flop, you need a clock. The verilog implementation can be found here, http://www.asic-world.com/examples/verilog/d_ff.html. Your implementation is actually a latch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a latch because you allow `q` to be updated when `ena` goes high or any time `d` changes when `ena` is high. This is exactly the behavior that describes a latch. This is how you should code a latch if you intentionally want to produce one.

To generate a flip-flop you should make the block triggered by a change in `ena` (i.e `always @(posedge ena)`) rather than by any change in the inputs.